# Question about Codeigniter url route

Tags: php, url, codeigniter

The `$route['page/(:num)']` in the route.php of codeigniter will accept only numbers in the urls, while the  `$route['page/(:any)']` will accept all the characters in the url. Is it possible to specify alpha-numeric values only? also letters only?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be nice, but according to the [docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html), you're going to need to use regular expressions.

```
$route['products/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)'] = "controller/method/$1";
```